# S3 CORS through CloudFront not working in Firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using `S3 CORS` for serving fonts. If `S3` domain name is used for serving fonts, it works in `Firefox`, but when `CloudFront` is used, it doesn't. Works with `Google Chrome`.

My `CORS` configuration on `S3`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
 <CORSRule>
     <AllowedOrigin>http://*.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
     <MaxAgeSeconds>30000</MaxAgeSeconds>
     <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
     <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 <CORSRule>
     <AllowedOrigin>https://*.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
     <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
     <MaxAgeSeconds>30000</MaxAgeSeconds>
     <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
     <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: FYI, it works with Google Chrome because Google Chrome doesn't care about CORS for webfonts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for me to get this working.  I had to set the CORS configuration to include the CloudFront distribution domain.

I also had to change the settings in my CloudFront distribution behaviors, to Allow forwarding of query strings.  I cant recall where I saw that was a requirement.

I then invalidated the fonts causing the issues.

Then we were good to go!

hope that helps

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://*.domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://*.domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://d2e7ljkkwgm4dt.cloudfront.net</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://dpibywtcfxy6z.cloudfront.net</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```